# Fyne get listableURI

Tags: go, path, uri, filepicker, fyne

Is there a way to get a listableURI anymore?
[image]

```
fdialog := widget.NewButton("", func() {
                locationURI := storage.NewFileURI("myfilepath")
                listableURI, err := storage.ListerForURI(locationURI)
        if err != nil {}
        fd := dialog.NewFileOpen(func(uri fyne.URIReadCloser, err error) {
            if uri != nil {
                fmt.Println("Selected File : ", uri.URI())
            }
        }, w2)
        fd.SetLocation(listableURI)
        fd.Show()
    })
```

I get an error message over `listableURI` when passed into the `SetLocation` function as:

```
cannot use listableURI (variable of type "fyne.io/fyne".ListableURI) as 
"fyne.io/fyne/v2".ListableURI value in argument to fd.SetLocation: 
"fyne.io/fyne".ListableURI does not implement "fyne.io/fyne/v2".
ListableURI (missing method Authority)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign
```

I've checked the methods in the storage and dialog packages and I can only find the `ListerForURI` method that returns a `listableURI`, but it seems to be missing a method call `Authority`. Any ideas? Is it possible to add a method with that name into the current listableURI, and what would that look like?

Comment: The error is telling you the issue: you're using `ListableURI` from `fyne.io/fyne`, but it's expecting `ListableURI` from `fyne.io/fyne/v2` (notice the `/v2`). Check your import in that file to make sure it's `fyne.io/fyne/v2` instead of just `fyne.io/fyne`.

Comment: I didn't even import `fyne.io/fyne`, only the v2 version

Comment: What is the `storage` package, how are you importing it, and does it have the incorrect import?

Comment: @Gavin that was it! It was the import from the old fyne. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.